# Issuing individual credits

Tags: magento-2.1.3

How can we issue individual credits that are all different amounts manually on our clients' accounts?
We have searched in Credit Memo section and can't see how we can manually edit or add a credit to one client, and a different credit to another, and a third credit amount to a third client, etc.